# Finding last Clockings in table

Tags: sql

Im trying to write a query to select all the last clocking in a table:

Table:Clockings

```
ID  Name                 Clock_Date   Clock_Time           Terminal 

1  Bob                   01012022     070502               In
2  Gavin                 01012022     071013               In
1  Bob                   01012022     163012               Out
2  Gavin                 01012022     173234               Out
3  Mike                  02012022     082343               In
3  Mike                  02012022     115410               Out
3  Mike                  02012022     142357               In  
4  Sam                   02012022     052345               In
4  Sam                   02012022     055512               Out   
1  Bob                   02012022     065342               In
2  Gavin                 02012022     084712               In
```

I would like to only get the last In clockings

Results :

```
1   Bob    02012022           065342        In
2   Gavin  02012022           084712        In 
3   Mike   02012022           142357        In
```

Sorry the first time im editing and i cant get it right

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function:

```
select t.*
from(select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by clock_date desc, clock_time desc) as seq
     from t
     where terminal = 'In'
    ) t
where seq = 1;
```